# Create live audio stream from line in device for HTML5

Tags: c#, html, audio-streaming, naudio

I am using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) to capture an audio signal from my line in device into a byte array. I can successfully send that byte array across my WLAN via UDP broadcast and receive it on another computer.  Once the byte array has been received, I am able to play the audio stream.

My goal is to stream an audio signal from a line in device so it can be consumed by an HTML5 audio tag or [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/). Do you have an example or reading material on how to convert the input byte array to stream as compatible HTML5 format?

I would to to create a .Net solution without using any third party applications.

Here is a sample of how I am capturing and broadcasting the audio signal via UDP.

```
var waveIn = new WaveInEvent();
waveIn.DeviceNumber = deviceID;
waveIn.WaveFormat = Program.WAVEFORMAT;
waveIn.BufferMilliseconds = 50;
waveIn.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;

var udpSender = new UdpClient();
udpSender.JoinMulticastGroup(Program.MulticastIP);

waveIn.StartRecording();

private void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    udpSender.Send(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded, Program.EndPoint);
}
```

Comment: Can you post details how you send and receive the signal? Or If you have example project please share with us. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is really dependent on whether you want to stream the audio to a HTML5 compatible browser, or whether you simply want to playback recorded audio.

According to W3Schools, all major browsers support the major audio formats (wav/ogg/mp3):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Playing a pre-recorded audio file using the HTML5 `audio` tag is pretty easy. The link above describes how to accomplish that.

Live-streaming the audio to a HTML5 browser is a whole different story. You need some kind of streaming server. I would advise against trying to implement this yourself. It's much easier to just use an external library for this.

The only reliable solution I can think of right now is using one of the freely available .Net P/Invoke libraries for libvlc, which provides access to the streaming capabilities of the VLC Media Player.

The following StackOverflow question describes how to setup an audio streaming server using libvlc:

[Use libvlc to stream mp3 to network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845588/use-libvlc-to-stream-mp3-to-network)

You can try to accomplish the same thing in C#. It might require some P/Invoke work, but it's the most realiable solution I can think of.